# Variable becomes undefined inside node function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node and having trouble with a simple function. Essentially the function accepts an entity name (ownerEntity) and looks up that entity's url and port number to serve a GET request.

However, when calling the function, it throws an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;URL&#39; of undefined`

The function is as follows:

```
const config = require('./index.js');

module.exports = function dataServerUrl(ownerEntity) {

    console.log(ownerEntity);
    console.log(config.DATA_SERVER);
    console.log(config.DATA_SERVER.ownerEntity); 

    const url = config.DATA_SERVER.ownerEntity.URL;
    const port = config.DATA_SERVER.ownerEntity.PORT;

    const urlParameter = url + ':' + port;

    return urlParameter;
};
```

The lookup hits an entry point `index.js` file in a folder called `config` that looks like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  DATA_SERVER: {
    1111: {
      URL: process.env.SERVER_1_URL,
      PORT: process.env.SERVER_1_PORT,
    },
    2222: {
      URL: process.env.SERVER_2_URL,
      PORT: process.env.SERVER_2_PORT,
    },
    3333: {
      URL: process.env.SERVER_3_URL,
      PORT: process.env.SERVER_3_PORT,
    },
  },
};
```

For testing I put three console logs in. The `console.log`s return the following so I can see that the `ownerEntity` variable is getting through initially, that the DATA_SERVER arguments come back, but somehow `ownerEntity` becomes undefined when looking up the URL.

```
1111
{ '1111': { URL: '0.0.0.0', PORT: '8080' },
  '2222': { URL: '192.168.99.100', PORT: '8080' },
  '3333': { URL: '192.168.99.100', PORT: '8081' } }
undefined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `config.DATA_SERVER[ownerEntity].URL`

Comment: Thanks @Derek that fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean:

```
config.DATA_SERVER[ownerEntity]
```

And therefore

```
const url = config.DATA_SERVER[ownerEntity].URL;
const port = config.DATA_SERVER[ownerEntity].PORT;
```

Use bracket notation for dynamic property names (like those provided by variables and such).